# Using Ajax to submit form from jQuery tabs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am having problems submitting a form on the second tab, as the the page is reloading and submitting the first tab. I understand this can be solved using Ajax. I have read some other posts but haven't quite grasped it so any explanation would be great.

I would like the form to load a different page the same way 'action' works within a HTML form.

The code below shows part of the HTML and jQuery.

What Ajax and where would it need to be placed in order for the second and on going tabs to post the data inputted in the particular tab.

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tab-links" style= "margin-top: 50px; width:700px;">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1"><p>Advert Space</p></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2"><p>Vouchers</p></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3"><p>Business 2 Business</p></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4"><p>Search Space Ads</p></a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content" >
        <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
            <h4 style="font-weight: 100">Display your advert</h4>
            <?php include ('advertinfo.php')?>
        </div>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
        var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');


        jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();
        jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Here is a copy of the form code

```
    <form action="advertupload.php" method= "post">
<dl>
<dd><input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo ($_SESSION['myname']) ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="approval" value="N">
<input type="hidden"  name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>"/>
<dt><p>Which advert space would you like to use?</p>
<dd><select name="location" id="textfield">
  <option value="0">Header</option>
  <option value="1">Location 1</option>
  <option value="2">Location 2</option>
  <option value="3">Location 3</option>
  <option value="4">Location 4</option>
  <option value="5">Location 5</option>
  <option value="6">Location 6</option>
</select>
<dt><p>When would you like to start your advert?</p>
<dd><input type="date" name="startdate" id="textfield">
<dt><p>When would you like your advert to end?</p>
<dd><input type="date" name="enddate" id="textfield">
<dt><button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 40px;"><p style="margin-top:1px; color: #fff">Next</p></a></button></td>
</dl>
```

Comment: Do You need to collect and submit data from both tabs?

Comment: @ZeJur Not at the same time, each form on each tab is independent. They are just different options.

There are four tabs with four different forms all with different purposes.

Comment: And u need to stay on that tab after the data is sent?

Comment: Would be great to see other forms!

Comment: I can't see any input field with type="file" in your form. Why you need
enctype="multipart/form-data" ?

Comment: The other forms are yet to be created, they are nearly the same just inputting into different tables on the database. Once the form has been submitted it will load up another page with an image upload (already created and working) called advertupload.php.

Comment: @ZeJur Originally the file upload was within this form, I have just forgotten to take it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100816/discussion-between-zejur-and-james-parsons).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you could submit the forms using AJAX:
http://codepen.io/medinasod/pen/QyqMKZ

**JS**

```
  jQuery("document").ready(function() {

    jQuery(".tab1Form, .tab2Form, .tab3Form").submit(function() {
      event.preventDefault();
      var fields = jQuery("input", this).serializeArray();
      jQuery("#results").empty();
      jQuery.each(fields, function(i, field) {
        jQuery("#results").append(field.value + " ");
      });
      jQuery.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "advertupload.php",
          data: fields
        })
        .done(function(msg) {
          console.log("Data Saved: " + msg);
          window.location.assign("/advertupload.php");
        });

    });

  });
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
      <form class="tab1Form">
      <dl>
      <dd><input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo ($_SESSION['myname']) ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="approval" value="N">
      <input type="hidden"  name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>"/>
      <dt><p>Which advert space would you like to use?</p>
      <dd><select name="location" id="textfield">
        <option value="0">Header</option>
        <option value="1">Location 1</option>
        <option value="2">Location 2</option>
        <option value="3">Location 3</option>
        <option value="4">Location 4</option>
        <option value="5">Location 5</option>
        <option value="6">Location 6</option>
      </select>
      <dt><p>When would you like to start your advert?</p>
      <dd><input type="date" name="startdate" id="textfield">
      <dt><p>When would you like your advert to end?</p>
      <dd><input type="date" name="enddate" id="textfield">
      <dt><button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 40px;"><p style="margin-top:1px; color: #fff">Next</p></a></button><span id="results"></span></td>
      </dl>
      </div>
```

**Reference:** Sample code was taken from the [jQuery AJAX API](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and the [jQuery serializeArray() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/).

Comment: Thanks, this works great however collects data from all tabs rather than from just the form on the selected tab. Is there a way to make that work?

Comment: Try changing line 4 in the JS to this: `var fields = jQuery("input", this).serializeArray();`

Comment: Thanks @medinasod, that works on tab 1 but the following tabs do not work. Also is there a way to load 'advertupload.php' once the submit button has been pressed.

Comment: You have to select form by `class` name or by `name` attribute. If your forms have the same `id` then js will take the first one for processing. But anyhow `id` must be unique! If u select by `class` or `name` attribute then as `submit` selector u can use a list of all your forms `class`'es etc. Like: `$('.class1, .class2, .class3').submit (){ ... }` also u can find which tab is active, and process only that form.

Comment: @ZeJur is right. Using class names for each form in the jQuery selector should solve the problem. I updated my answer.

Comment: @JamesParsons You could add a redirect to the "done" callback:       `.done(function(msg) {
        console.log("Data Saved: " + msg);
      window.location.assign("advertupload.php");
      });`

Comment: @ZeJur. How would you find the active tab? I believe this would fix my problem that is similar to James'

Comment: @RaymondWachaga, there are many ways to find out which tab is active. If you're using some css/js framework, just inspect that tab to see what was changed after it become active. Or you can append your own class/data-attr on tab click like: `$('tab1').on('click',function(){ $(this).addClass('is-active') });`